# JSON expects a string for the 8 character number, how do I enclose with quotes

Tags: php, json

I have the following json, the it is not valid due to the json below, I need to make it a string in order to be jsonically valid. any suggestions as to the best way to do this in php?

```
{
    29646191: [
        "https://www.facebook.com/RobertScoble/posts/480030845352725",
        "https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg",
        "Today I tried... | Facebook",
        "Robert Scoble wrote: Today I tried something. I paid $49 and... Join Facebook to connect with Robert Scoble and others you may know.",
        null,
        [
            "//images3-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url\u003dhttps://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg\u0026container\u003dfocus\u0026gadget\u003da\u0026rewriteMime\u003dimage/*\u0026refresh\u003d31536000\u0026resize_h\u003d150\u0026resize_w\u003d150\u0026no_expand\u003d1",
            150,
            150,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            [
                3,
                "https://images1-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url\u003dhttps://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg\u0026container\u003dfocus\u0026gadget\u003dhttps://plus.google.com\u0026rewriteMime\u003dimage/*\u0026resize_h\u003d800\u0026resize_w\u003d800\u0026no_expand\u003d1"
            ]
        ],
        "//s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain\u003dwww.facebook.com",
        [],
        null,
        []
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just like you said in the title of the question: put the number in double quotes.

Comment: Is it so much to ask for formatted code?

Comment: I did it while you did, sorry I took so long.

Comment: @RayToal in php, I need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the browser do it for you.

```
var x = {
    29646191: [
        "https://www.facebook.com/RobertScoble/posts/480030845352725",
        "https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg",
        "Today I tried... | Facebook",
        "Robert Scoble wrote: Today I tried something. I paid $49 and... Join Facebook to connect with Robert Scoble and others you may know.",
        null,
        [
            "//images3-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url\u003dhttps://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg\u0026container\u003dfocus\u0026gadget\u003da\u0026rewriteMime\u003dimage/*\u0026refresh\u003d31536000\u0026resize_h\u003d150\u0026resize_w\u003d150\u0026no_expand\u003d1",
            150,
            150,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            [
                3,
                "https://images1-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url\u003dhttps://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg\u0026container\u003dfocus\u0026gadget\u003dhttps://plus.google.com\u0026rewriteMime\u003dimage/*\u0026resize_h\u003d800\u0026resize_w\u003d800\u0026no_expand\u003d1"
            ]
        ],
        "//s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain\u003dwww.facebook.com",
        [],
        null,
        []
    ]
}

JSON.stringify(x);
```

Gives

> "{"29646191":["https://www.facebook.com/RobertScoble/posts/480030845352725","https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg","Today
>   I tried... | Facebook","Robert Scoble wrote: Today I tried something.
>   I paid $49 and... Join Facebook to connect with Robert Scoble and
>   others you may
>   know.",null,["//images3-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url=https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg&container=focus&gadget=a&rewriteMime=image/*&refresh=31536000&resize_h=150&resize_w=150&no_expand=1",150,150,null,null,null,null,null,[3,"https://images1-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url=https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg&container=focus&gadget=https://plus.google.com&rewriteMime=image/*&resize_h=800&resize_w=800&no_expand=1"]],"//s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.facebook.com",[],null,[]]}"

Comment: json_Encode works, but does not let me pull an associative array, I can email you where this is being applied with more code if that would help.